# Sending message from webview to extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have one webview (`SidebarProvider`) which allows the user to type an input and send it. I want to send such input to an extension `SearchedWordPanel`.

Steps:

1. In my Sidebar View (html, js and css), the user types a word and press "search". **(Works)**
2. The word is sent to the SidebarProvider which receives the message using `onDidReceiveMessage` and runs the command to display the SearchedWordPanel. **(Works)**
3. The `SearchedWordPanel` opens and displays the word the user has input. **(Question)**

I am able to do point 1 and 2 but not sending the searched word to the `SearchedWordPanel`.

**extensions.ts**

```
const sidebarProvider = new SidebarProvider(context.extensionUri);
  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider(
      "vsmyapp-sidebar",
      sidebarProvider
    )
  );

context.subscriptions.push(
  vscode.commands.registerCommand('vsmyapp.showSearched', () => {
    SearchedWordPanel.kill();
    SearchedWordPanel.createOrShow(context.extensionUri);
  })
);
```

**SidebarView**

```
<button on:click={() =>
  tsvscode.postMessage({
    type: 'onSearch',
    value: searchedText
  })
}>Search</button>
```

**SidebarProvider**

```
webviewView.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(async (data) => {
  switch (data.type) {
    case "onSearch" : {
      if (!data.value) {
        return;
      }
      vscode.window.showInformationMessage(data.value); <-- WORKS
      vscode.commands.executeCommand( <--WORKS, the command is run. BUT How do I send data.value to SearchedWordPanel?
        "vsmyapp.showSearched",
      );
      COMMAND_THAT_SENDS_(data.value)_TO_SearchedWordPanel // Pseudocode
      break;
    }
```

**Question**: how can I send `data.value` to `SearchedWordPanel` when I execute `vscode.commands.executeCommand("vsmyapp.showSearched");` in `SidebarProvider`?

Comment: please let us know if you resolved this issue. I am stuck with the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Webview has `postMessage` - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#passing-messages-from-an-extension-to-a-webview.

I'm not sure what `SearchedWordPanel` is (It's not a `WebviewPanel`), probably a wrapper.

Let's say `SearchedWordPanel` has the native `WebviewPanel` as prop `panel`. In order to post a message to it, you can do:

```
SearchedWordPanel.panel.postMessage()
```

Comment: I would like to send the message from `SidebarProvider` to `SearchedWordPanel`. Not from `SearchedWordPanel`.
I added the location where I want to send the message with the pseudo code `COMMAND_THAT_SENDS_(data.value)_TO_SearchedWordPanel`

Comment: Option 1: Depends on the extension structure but you might be able to pass `SearchedWordPanel` instance to `SidebarProvider` when you create it (Like [here](https://github.com/moshfeu/vscode-compare-folders/blob/ae0956fed655692dfe27ac9616b0e23bf8bf5143/src/providers/foldersCompareProvider.ts#L45)) so later you can call its `postMessage`.

Comment: Option 2 (actually it should be 1): Since you exec `vsmyapp.showSearched` and in extension.ts you listen to that command, you can have the instance there (If you don't have it already) so you can call the `postMessage` from there. I believe my explanations are fuzzy. If I could see the actual structure I might be able to help more.